# Calling Firestore's get(/databases/) function where the relevant data is within a sub-collection ... What's going wrong?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore, I have data within a sub-collection called 'exclusiveB', and a field of this collection's documents is 'creditCard' which accepts boolean values.

Within the same Firestore referred to above, I have another sub-collection called 'exclusiveA'.

I wrote a security rule for enabling the 'exclusiveA' collection to be read by the current user: if the current user has a uid, and if details concerning the current-user in sub-collection 'exclusiveB' confirm field-value 'creditCard' as false.

The result received is that Firestore has denied the read permission (despite the 'creditCard' field-value is false).  Can anyone explain why and offer a solution please?

Please note that the parent collections 'users', 'userA', and 'userB' are empty except for a single value that confirms the iD of the document holding sub-collections, and, 'exclusiveB' documents feature a field that confirms the current-user's uid, and another field that confirms the document's iD.

Photos of the Firestore formation are as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The security rules are:

```css
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
  
  match /users {
      // if a rule isn't specified, Firestore denies by default
        allow read;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userA {
        allow read;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userB {
        allow read;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userA/{docId2}/exclusiveA/{docId3} {
  
    // allow read if user: (1) has a uid, (2) has creditcard = false
        allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/{docId}/userB/{docIdB}/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.creditCard == false;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userB/{docId2}/exclusiveB/{xcluB} {
        allow get: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userA/{docId2}/otherDetails/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userB/{docId2}/otherDetails/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.id;
  }

  }

}
```

The Flutter code for the Firestore query at the user-interface level is:

```css
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class StreamResults extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StreamResults> createState() => _StreamResultsState();
}

class _StreamResultsState extends State<StreamResults> {
  final _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _dB = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _dataSource = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(
          'users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userA/2VzSHur3RllcF5PojT61/exclusiveA');

  String? vehicleMake, vehicleTitle, currentUserID, pCurrency, currency, uid, docRefID;
  int? maxSpeed, pullStrength;

  void getIdentity() {
    currentUserID = _auth.currentUser!.uid;
    print('The current user\'s ID is: $currentUserID.');
  }
  
  Future<void> matchDetails() async {
    final exclusiveBcollection = await _dB.collection('users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userB/mv6YgmAfIDEkUNmstrzg/exclusiveB')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUserID).get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            currency = doc['currency'];
            uid = doc['uid'];
            docRefID = doc['docRefID'];
          });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getIdentity();
    matchDetails();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _dataSource.where('preferredCurrency', isEqualTo: currency).snapshots().distinct(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final retrievedData = snapshot.data!.docs;
            for (var specific in retrievedData) {
              maxSpeed = specific['topSpeed'];
              vehicleTitle = specific['vehicleName'];
              pullStrength = specific['horsePower'];
              vehicleMake = specific['vehicleBrand'];
              pCurrency = specific['preferredCurrency'];
              print('The vehicle\'s maximum speed = $maxSpeed.');
              print('The vehicle\'s pulling strength = $pullStrength bph.');
              print(
                  'The vehicle\'s brand is $vehicleMake, and its model-name is $vehicleTitle.');
              print('The preferred currency = $pCurrency.');
            }
          }
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('The vehicle\'s maximum speed = $maxSpeed.'),
              Text('The vehicle\'s pulling strength = $pullStrength bph.'),
              Text(
                  'The vehicle\'s brand is $vehicleMake, and its model-name is $vehicleTitle.'),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

With thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedback from a Firebase representative (that I read today) basically amounts to an admission that Firestore's **get(/databases/)** function is poorly designed, and, that in the way I use Firestore, which is probably the way that you use it too, the get(/databases/) function will never ever work!

The explanation given was that the $(request.auth.uid) aspect of the get(/databases/) function seeks a document within the relevant collection that has an identity that is equal to the unique-identity of the current user.

When creating new documents for Firestore, the identity of new documents is generated randomly (by my choice), and this seems the best way and the right way, especially considering privacy and data protection.

The random creation of a Firestore document's identity means that Firestore would never ever create a document that has the same identity as the current user, which means that the get(/databases/) call will never find a document with the same identity as the current user, which means that the get(/databases/) call will always return 'false' meaning it would be consistently fruitless and clients like myself would consistently find it not-working.

The official response,

> "*The call to get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))  will load a single document in the Cloud Firestore database (not a collection, or a sub-collection). The given path is an "absolute path" and must begin with  /databases/$(database)/documents. The value of $(request.auth.uid) will be replaced by the UID of the currently-logged in user. For example, if the UID of the currently-logged in user is "user123" then the get(...) call will load the document at the path users/user123.*"

Source: https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/WJ7oZ793260

Solution: We need to request an update of Firestore's technology for changes to the get(/databases/) function, so that its successor does what we have expected the get(/databases/) function to do.  Smart and convenient functionality would be an asset to the Firestore product and to its clients.

Dear Firebase Team, please take note of the above.

Comment: It's a disappointment and a let down and a lot of time wasted actually.  Could anyone recommend a Firestore alternative please?  Right now I cannot think of a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
  final _dataSource = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(
          'users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userA/2VzSHur3RllcF5PojT61/exclusiveA');

  _dataSource.where('preferredCurrency', isEqualTo: currency).snapshots().distinct(),
```

And this query:

```
    final exclusiveBcollection = await _dB.collection('users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userB/mv6YgmAfIDEkUNmstrzg/exclusiveB')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: currentUserID).get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
```

Both attempt to `list` documents the subcollection, from the perspective of security rules.  But your rules only allow individual document `get` operations:

```
  match /users/{docId}/userA/{docId2}/exclusiveA/{docId3} {
        allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/{docId}/userB/{docIdB}/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.creditCard == false;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userB/{docId2}/exclusiveB/{xcluB} {
        allow get: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
  }
```

If you want to query (`list`) a collection, you will need to add that permission.  You can do that by specifying `list`, or just using `read`, which is a combination of `get` and `list`, as discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

```
  match /users/{docId}/userA/{docId2}/exclusiveA/{docId3} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/{docId}/userB/{docIdB}/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.creditCard == false;
  }
  
  match /users/{docId}/userB/{docId2}/exclusiveB/{xcluB} {
        allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Doug, thank you for your response.  I think I understand: the query I wrote in Flutter demands a 'list' kind of read whereas my security rules have only granted permission for a 'get' kind of read.  I will make the changes you have suggested shortly and comment further afterwards  Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Doug, I changed 'list' to 'read' and retested but the result is the same ... The permission is denied.

Comment: I believe there must be a bug at work for get(/databases/) function calls.  Bugs of this kind can be reported here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs

Comment: The other problem is that you're using `{}` placeholders inside the document path, which is incorrect. That's only how you match path segements.  If you want variable substitution, use `$()`, which you are already doing once.

Comment: If you want better diagnostics while testing out rules, you should use the local emulator for that.  Applying complex rules in production is difficult because you don't get feedback on what's wrong.

Comment: Okay. I've made the following change: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(docId)/userB/$(docId2)/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.creditCard == false; (permission = denied)

Comment: I watched a video and set up the emulator for testing recently, but that hasn't prevented me from my current position.  I didn't find a certainty of emulating the situation of this enquiry, so I was left with different examples and confidence in other rules only.

Comment: Hi @Doug, Could you emulate my circumstance above within a Firestore and Flutter interface near you and draft the corresponding firestore rule to test and clarify the correct get(/databases/) call please?  The main thing here is for the relevant data to be two sub-collections deep from the parent.  With some photos I could then replicate what you show and finally understand - if that's possible.

Comment: I don't actively use the emulator or Flutter at all, and I'm an unpaid volunteer on this side, so it's a bit much to ask.  I suggest taking some time to debug yourself and share your results in a question explaining what you've done and how it doesn't behave the way you expect.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear you say that.  I thought the idea was a really good way for you to showcase your expertise, not just for me, but for anyone else experiencing this roadblock.  And since you mention it, examples of your expertise would supplement your CV ... As an alternative, could you draft the get(/databases/) call fitting to the circumstances here?

Comment: I have answered over 9000 questions on Stack Overflow and have a distinguished career that doesn't need any more augmentation. I'm busy at work at an early stage startup now and can't really afford to take time away from that for this level of volunteer work. I strongly suggest taking time to do the debugging work on this using the tools available to boost your own skills and abilities, and use that to unblock yourself the best you can. Even if you don't get to the end, you will be able to present more complete information so that a volunteer can more easily help you.

Comment: I suppose that if you knew the solution then you'd resolve this one. It's just a simple question after all, and doesn't require a confirmation of your academic credentials or your lifetime achievements. I can admit that I have no idea here, hence with humility I composed this question.

Comment: I don't know the answer, and I don't have the time to find out.  I'm sorry - I've done my best by pointing out two things that were obviously wrong to me.  Instead of taking the time to debug myself, I have recommended a tool that is known to help you with that.  Please post again if you have more information after using that tool to more closely debug this situation.

Comment: Thanks again for the guidance that you gave, but the way it looks to me, is that Firestore's response to perfectly written code is suggestive of a flaw that is not my fault, and would have to be a flaw with Firestore itself.  That coupled with a lack of solutions here at Stack Overflow (the issue being fairly basic) further suggests that this topic/issue is a hot-spot.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, then send your complete reproduction instructions to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found that calling **exists**(/databases/) on the data relevant to the get(/databases/) call, first, activated the perfectly written get(/databases/) call.  It seems like a fault, but another way of looking at it could be to say that Firestore will accept a get(/databases/) call if it is aware of the relevant data ahead of the get(/databases/) call.

```css
match /users/{docId}/userA/{docId2}/exclusiveA/{docId3} {
  
    // allow read if user: (1) has a uid, (2) has creditcard = false
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(docId)/userB/$(docId2)/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)) &&
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(docId)/userB/$(docId2)/exclusiveB/$(request.auth.uid)).data.creditCard == false;
  }
```

Comment: Turns out that it isn't the end (as I put it) because on the Android emulator the call works and the read is allowed, but on the iOS emulator the read is still dis-allowed.

Comment: On the Android emulator, the read was allowed but later comes the error message: W/Firestore(24205): (24.4.3) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userA/2VzSHur3RllcF5PojT61/exclusiveA order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
D/EGL_emulation(24205): app_time_stats: avg=15753.46ms min=383.96ms max=31122.96ms count=2

Answer (score 0):

My answer (2) - still doesn't work - but appears to be a step in the direction of my desired result:

Firestore also accepts the real path-name for get(/databases/) function calls, and for the 'match' path definitions too.  These will be less-confusing techniques if useful, especially for debugging and understanding where the wrong step is.

**Example**

```css
match /users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userA/2VzSHur3RllcF5PojT61/exclusiveA/ {docId3} {
  
    // allow read if creditCard in exclusiveB = false
        
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/l9NzQFjN4iB0JlJaY3AI/userB/mv6YgmAfIDEkUNmstrzg/exclusiveB).data.creditCard == false;
  }
```

The **/$(request.auth.uid)** aspect is missing and might be the final piece for achieving the desired result.  I would write a third answer once that last piece is understood.